# apply where clause and column limitations on EF queries before sending them to SQL Server

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I'm beginner in EF 6.0 and I've started to design an easy to use DAL.
Here is my interface for all operational task on each entities :

```
public interface IEntity<T>
{
    T Insert(T NewItem);
    T Update(T ModifiedItem);
    bool Delete(T Selected);
    bool DeleteByID(int ItemID);
    List<T> Select(Func<T, bool> Query);
    IQueryable<T> GetQuery();
}
```

here is my implementation for Select method on 'Group' Entity:

```
public bool Select(Func<DataAccess.Model.Group, bool> Query, out List<Business.Entity.Login.LoginUser> Output)
{
    IQueryable<DataAccess.Model.Group> Connection = GetQuery();
    Output = Connection.Where(Query).ToLoginUser().ToList();
    return true;
}
```

I will receive all range limiters on fields using Func<,> parameter and I'm using below Extension Method to hide some of my not needed columns:

```
    public static IEnumerable<BEntities.Login.LoginUser> ToLoginUser(this IEnumerable<DataAccess.Model.Group> Model)
    {
        return from A in Model select new Business.Entity.Login.LoginUser { Username = A.Name, Password = A.Identifier };
    }
```

but what will actually runs on SQL Server (in diagnostic window) is :

```
SELECT
[Extent1].[ID] AS[ID],
[Extent1].[Identifier] AS [Identifier],
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name],
[Extent1].[ParentGroup] AS [ParentGroup],
[Extent1].[GroupPath] AS [GroupPath]
FROM[dbo].[Group] AS [Extent1]
```

I cant see any 'Where' clause or any column limitation on this query.
where is my mistake ?

Comment: Shortly, replace every `Func<...>` with `Expression<Func<...>>`

Answer (score 1):

using Expression<...,...> changed my generated SQL Query to something like it:

```
[Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
[Extent1].[Identifier] AS [Identifier], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent1].[ParentGroup] AS [ParentGroup], 
[Extent1].[GroupPath] AS [GroupPath]
FROM [dbo].[Group] AS [Extent1]
WHERE N'Noei' = [Extent1].[Name]
```

but i also used an model mapper to limit some of it's columns:

```
public static IEnumerable<BEntities.Login.LoginUser> ToLoginUser(this IEnumerable<DataAccess.Model.Group> Model) 
{
    return from A in Model select new Business.Entity.Login.LoginUser { Username = A.Name, Password = A.Identifier };
}
```

and i called it in this way:

```
public bool Select(Expression<Func<DataAccess.Model.Group, bool>> Query, out List<Business.Entity.Login.LoginUser> Output)
{
    IQueryable<DataAccess.Model.Group> Connection = GetQuery();
    Output = Connection.Where(Query).ToLoginUser().ToList();
    return true;
}
```

but i expected to see column hidings in generated Query.